Beam displacement at focal point
I'm working on a project that uses galvanometers with mirrors. They're configured to have a focal point of 175mm. The motors rotate at 1 mechanical degree per 500mV, that will be 2 degrees optical per 500mV. I understand that at the output from the mirror the beam will move at 2x the mechanical rotation of the motor. The challenge is to find what input voltage do I need to move the beam 1mm at the focal point.

May be you sketch your design, where is the motor etc.  What is a "mechanical" degree?

I suppose the focal point is the one of the mirrors. So the firs mirror at 500mv moves 1°, th second  the same. so the beam moves by 4°. Or do the two motors turn different the one right turn, the other left turn? the 1. motor moves the beam to the right, , the second down?
So you decide the angle and the movement of the second angle gives a displacement of $L*Phi$ with $Phi$
in rad. so $\phi=(degree/180)*2\pi$ where L is the distance of the mirror to the spot
